# How can I use threads in standard JAX-RS?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, jax-rs

I'm writing a small library targeting JAX-RS environment. And I'm planning to use `@Suspended AsyncResponse` for server-side utilization.

```java
public void writeFile(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                      InputStream entity) {

    // store entity to a temp file.

    // distribute temp file to siblings.
    for (URI sibling : siblings) {
        // send temp file to sibling // i want to use thread.
    }
}
```

I already know that using `@Suspended AsyncResponse` can make a higher throughput. And I wan to use threads for more throughput.

My question is how can I use threads in JAX-RS? Is it safe or even recommended?

Some examples show just starting a new Thread instance. Some examples show using Executor instance.

```java
@Inject Executor executor; // Is this automatically injected?

public void writeFile(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                      InputStream entity) {

    // store entity to a temp file.

    // distribute temp file to siblings.
    for (URI sibling : siblings) {
        // new Thread().start; // is this ok?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. See http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/#Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing

Comment: Of course, you should probably use an ExecutorService instead of starting the thread directly.